# MS Office Word 2016: enumeration turns into image @ PDF print

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, printing, images

Quite the odd title, isn't it?

My problem is as follows: I have different header styles, of which each is numbered, as per enumeration: chapter titles are e.g. "1 Chapter Title" (but of course, a bit beautier than here, I'll see if I can upload some images), section titles "1.1 Section TItle" etc.

Everything works just fine, until I print to pdf. I won't export to, or save as, pdf, since the font I'm working with just won't come out as beautiful as when I pick print to pdf (I use CutePDF Writer, but it basically has the same result as PDFCreator and other printers).

So what's my problem?

[image]

Don't see it?

[image]

There you go. The number turns into a non-selectable image.

This isn't such a pain in the a**, but here's some other examples ... Believe me, sometimes, it stands out, especially in the ToC:

[image]

[image]

[image]

As you can see, in the ToC, not only are all the numbers of enumeration turned into images, but also the whole lines at the 4th and 5th level (yes, 4th and 5th; you can't see level 1 in my screenshot, which is the level for "PART I" etc; level 2 is chapter).

This can be hugely annoying when having to turn in PDF files, but can also mess up printed versions of the PDF: you can genuinly see the numbers printed in a lower resolution image than the normal text.

Is someone familiar with this problem? Any way to fix this?

Thanks!

FSJ

Edit: they already appear as images in Word itself (Compare 1.1 Inleiding with 1.1.1 Algemene inleiding: "1.1.1 Algemene inleiding" is in a lower resolution image than the high resolution text of "Inleiding", yet note that "1.1" is also a lower resolution image):

[image]

Here's the same in Office 2010: note that it doesn't give a difference in resolution ...

[image]

Comment: I opened and printed the document in Office Word 2010, and it rendered as normal text, so it's a 2016 (via O365) issue. Anyone?

Comment: Could you upload a small example ?

Comment: Not reproducible with Word 2016. Again : Could you give us a small Word file as example?

Comment: Why not use  'save' with filetype as pd? I used to use Cute, but haven't needed to since Word could save directly as pdf. Different pdf printers will treat this in different ways and so your problem may be with Cute.

Comment: Like I said, the problem lies with Office 2016. It is absent with Office 2010. Even in the program itself (2016 vs 2010), differences in resolution of enumeration numbers in titles can be observed, as well as ToC entries at levels 4 and 5: normal text in Office 2010, but low-resolution image-like appearance in Office 2016. I don't use save as pdf because that will just not save the font I use the way I want to: it is fixed at low res and zooming in will screw up the 'experience' and make the letters pixel-ish. I don't feel like using another font, either, truth be told

Comment: In my test with Office 2016 & CutePDF I got text and not images. This might be a problem with your document. Again : Could you give us a small Word file as example?

Comment: Well. apparently you don't really want an answer, so why start a bounty?

Comment: Forgive me for not having all the time of the world to upload an example. I'll do so as soon as I can

Comment: You don't have time for us, and we don't have time for you.

Comment: Oh my what on earth did I trigger.